# setting connection time out for jax-ws client

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am trying to set the connection timeout for a jax-ws-webservice-client.
When deploying the app on Glassfish, it is not taking the timeouts set by:

```
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, timeoutInMillisecs);
```

I am setting timeoutInMillisecs to 60000. But I'm getting a connection time out exception in about 30 sec.

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set also `JAXWSProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT` to value `timeoutInMillisecs` (see [How to define connection and request timeouts for the client?](http://www.centurion.link/w/programming/java/jax#how_to_define_connection_and_request_timeouts_for_the_client)).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing else worked, except the below

```
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", "100");
```

This worked for me in GlassFish Application